# Which index to refresh after adding a new product

Tags: magento-1.8, reindex, index

To win some time on product changes i have set some indexes to manual.

Only "Product Prices" and "Stock Status" are set to "Update on save", all others are manual. A cron is sceduled to re-run indexes at an appropriate non-production hour (5am)

But which of the folowing indexes must be refreshed when adding a new product?

- Product attribute
- Product flat data
- Category flat data
- Categort Products
- Catalog search index
- Label Aggregatie Data
- Catalog Url rewrite

When doing all it takes up to 1-2 hours ....

We use magento 1.8.1 CE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience with a site that takes 4 hours to do a reindex, this is enough when handling products:

```
Catalog URL Rewrites
Product Flat Data (if you use flat tables)
Category Products
Catalog Search Index
```

Tag Aggregation Data (only if you use them)